# What is causing the unexpected token "=" within a for loop in my Groovy script?

Tags: groovy, apache-poi

I have been trying to customize the code from [this site](https://dzone.com/articles/the-programmers-way-to-convert-excel-to-csv) to convert the tables in an excel workbook to csv files. I've made a few small modifications above segment in question, and have only added a label to that segment as it was throwing a different error otherwise. I now get an unexpected token error on the first "=" in my for loop:

```
.groovy: 21: unexpected token: = @ line 21, column 16.
       for (int r = 0, rn = sheet.getLastRowNum() ; r <= rn ; r++) {
              ^

1 error
```

The entire script is included below. I've tried retyping the code to find any syntax errors but I fear it might just be a misunderstanding on my part of the way groovy interprets this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi', version='4.1.0')

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter

Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(this.args));
int sheetNo = Integer.parseInt(args[index++]);
FormulaEvaluator fe = null;
if ( index < args.length ) {
    fe = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
}
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(csvFile), true, "UTF-8");

byte[] bom = [(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF];
out.write(bom);
label:{
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNo);
    for (int r = 0, rn = sheet.getLastRowNum() ; r <= rn ; r++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
        if ( row == null ) { out.println(','); continue; }
        boolean firstCell = true;
        for (int c = 0, cn = row.getLastCellNum() ; c < cn ; c++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(c,    Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if ( ! firstCell ) out.print(',');
            if ( cell != null ) {
                if ( fe != null ) cell = fe.evaluateInCell(cell);
                String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                if ( cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA ) {
                    value = "=" + value;
                }
                out.print(encodeValue(value));
            }
            firstCell = false;
        }
        out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just split it on two statements:

```
int cn = row.getLastCellNum()
for (int c = 0 ; c < cn ; c++) {
  ...
```